# Real IP on nginx behind AWS ELB with IP filtering

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-elb

In our setup we have an AWS ELB sending public traffic to two EC2 instances running nginx.

These nginx's proxy to many apps, some of these app have IP restrictions on them, like:

```
  location /admin {
    allow 1.1.1.1;
    allow 1.1.1.2;
    deny all;
    proxy somewhere;
  }
```

The problem is I cannot get the real client IP - it shows up in the nginx logs as a private 172.31.0.0/16 address

I've tried adding:

```
    set_real_ip_from  0.0.0.0/0;
    real_ip_header    X-Forwarded-For;
    real_ip_recursive on;
```

But still don't get the real IP.

My nginx version:

```
    nginx version: nginx/1.4.6
    built by gcc 4.6.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5)
    TLS SNI support enabled
    configure arguments: --with-cc-opt='-g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Wformat-security -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2' --with-ld-opt='-Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro' --prefix=/usr/share/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --lock-path=/var/lock/nginx.lock --pid-path=/run/nginx.pid --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/body --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/fastcgi --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/proxy --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/scgi --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/uwsgi --with-debug --with-pcre-jit --with-ipv6 --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_realip_module --add-module=/tmp/nginx-sticky-module-1.1 --with-http_addition_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_spdy_module --with-http_sub_module --with-mail --with-mail_ssl_module
```

Comment: Was your ELB set up with an HTTP listener or TCP listener? If the latter, X-Forwarded-For won't be set.